# Copy rotation after 180° bone, How to fix this behavior?

Tags: bones

I have 3 bones (2 feet and 1 torso), I made the torso be between the feet bones using the influence of 0.5 for each.
[image]

However when I make a 180° degree turn, the torso bone act strangely.
[image]

I want the torso bone to be parallel to the feet bones after the turn of 180°
How can I fix this?

Comment: You have posted a behavior and stated it is a problem, but not why it is a problem or what you are looking for, so we are helpless to provide assistance.  

I will point you have multiple copy constraints on one bone, which doesn't make a lot of sense.  Those constraints will come together unpredictably, so you shouldn't have more than one.

Comment: I want to make the torso bone be always on the middle of the feet bones and have an average rotation of the feet bones.
In the picture I wanted the torso bone to be parallel to the feet bones after 180°.
How should I do it?